# Sql query to regroup audit information

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions, unpivot

I have a SQL Server database where there is an history table containing a record each time the said record, in another table, changes.

The source data table:

| Id | DataA | DataB | DataC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Truc | Much | Bazar |

The history table:

| DataId | Time | Username | DataA | DataB | DataC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 12:00:00 | User1 | Truc | Much | Bazar |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 06:00:00 | User1 | Truc | Much | Bazar2 |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | User1 | Truc | Much2 | Bazar2 |

Meaning the record 1 of the data table has been updated 3 times by user "User1", He changed "Much2" to "Much" and "Bazar2" to "Bazar". The last record (first line) being the current state.

I would like to make a query that shows the audit in a way we can see which column has been updated, with the old value, the new one, and by who and when

In this example, it will be like this:

| DataId | Time | Username | Column | Old value | New value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 12:00:00 | User1 | DataC | Bazar2 | Bazar |
| 2 | 2023-01-01 06:00:00 | User1 | DataB | Much2 | Much |

I'm clearly not an expert in SQL, and I don't really know how to handle this. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unpivot your data columns to rows, then use window functions to identify values that changed:

```
select dataid, time, username, col, lag_val as old_value, val as new_value
from (
    select t.*, v.*,
        lag(val, 1, val) over(partition by dataid, col order by time) lag_val
    from mytable t
    cross apply ( values ('DataA', DataA), ('DataB', DataB), ('DataC', DataC) ) v(col, val)
) t
where val <> lag_val
order by dataid, time
```

| dataid | time | username | col | old_value | new_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 06:00:00.000 | User1 | DataB | Much2 | Much |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 12:00:00.000 | User1 | DataC | Bazar2 | Bazar |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OJ6l-4IR)

Comment: You, sir, are a true sql king :) Thank you so much !